# Relations between good ordinary reduction for $E/\mathbb{Q}$ and for $E/K$ with $K$ number field

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Reading some articles and Silvermann's "The arithmetic of elliptic curves" I found these two different definitions for good **ordinary** reduction.

Silvermann, with Theorem V.3.1, says that an elliptic curve defined over a finite field with characteristic $p$ is ordinary if, for example, $E[p^r]=\mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$ for every $r\in\mathbb{N}$. This implicitely says that an elliptic curve $E/K$ defined over a number field has (good) ordinary reduction at a place $v$ of $K$ if the reduction $\tilde{E}_v$ is ordinary.

From the other hand, I read in many articles that for elliptic curves $E/\mathbb{Q}$ the condition of having a (good) ordinary reduction at $p$ is equivalent to the condition
\begin{equation*}
p\nmid a_p:=p+1-|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|.
\end{equation*}

Why is the last condition equivalent to the first?

Comment: Shouldn't the group $E[n]$ have order $n^2$?

Comment: What you say is true if the characteristic $p$ of the field doesn't divide $n$. Otherwise, the structure of $E[n]$ depends on the fact that $E$ is ordinary or not at $p$. Check Corollary III.3.4 and Theorem V.3.1 of Silvermann